# Reaching out to hackspaces

Tags: discussion, community, new-users, hackspaces

In order to get more knowledgeable<sup>1</sup> active users I think it would be worthwhile reaching out to all the hackspace<sup>2</sup> communities out there.

- I've asked questions of my local hackspace and got great answers before.
- They have many users with questions and many skilled professional engineers who also have community awareness and answering skills.
- Many very similar questions are asked over and over in all these communities worldwide - Engineering.SE is exactly the solution to this problem.

So here are my questions and discussion starter:

Is this a good idea and how should we go about it? I can think of lots of pros, are there any cons? Should it be coordinated? What specifically do we want to say to these maker communities? Any other comments?

<sup>1. That is an increased number of knowledgeable users rather than users who know more than our current users.

2. a.k.a hackerspace; makerspace; hack-lab; maker-shed; community workshops; and many other names.</sup>

Comment: My school's actually starting a makerspace, so I'll see what I can do there. Great idea.

Comment: One idea may be to source answers to specific problems the hackspace is encountering with a project to the site.  There's no better advertising in the world than solving problems for other people.

Comment: Very good point. Maybe I could re-post questions being asked in my local hackspace mailing list and then point them to an answer. Though I'd kind of rather they ask it themselves... but you're right, a solved problem is pretty much the best advertising you can do!

Answer (score 2):

**Yes.**  I can't think of any downsides.

Perhaps someone can ask Stack Exchange for some Engineering.SE swag for hackspaces, or to sponsor a hackspace social in a way that highlights the Engineering beta site?

What about a hackspace competition to design a make that embodies Engineering.SE ?