# Should hackspaces have their own tags?

Tags: discussion, tags, hackspaces

As a follow-up to [this question](https://engineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/191/95):

Should we allow hackspaces to have their own tags?

I think this is an interesting idea, but I'm not sure about how well it would fit into the SE format, or if it would be accepted/appreciated by the wider community.

Some Pros:

- People can follow their local hackspace and easily see questions from people in their own local community, get involved helping out with projects, etc.
- It can help existing communities cooperate with the wider global community while retaining some identity and thus extending their community spirit outwards
- It encourages a great open/sharing mindset within the Engineering.SE community

Some Cons:

- Other organisations such as large engineering corporations may want/expect their own tags, or users may assume this is ok and create them
- Such tags wouldn't be about any specific engineering subject so may confuse some users
- It may be difficult to name them clearly and consistently because hackspaces tend to create their own identity rather than following a consistent naming convention

I would love to hear people's thoughts on this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## No.

Organizations do not get tags. They are [meta-tags](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/) and should be burned with prejudice:

> #### From this point on, meta-tagging is explicitly discouraged.
>
> How can you tell you’re using a meta-tag? It’s easier than you might
> think.
>
> 1. **If the tag can’t work as the *only* tag on a question, it’s probably a meta-tag.** Every tag you use should be able to work, more
>    or less, as the *only* tag on a question. Meta-tags, like [beginner],
>    [subjective], and [best-practices], are useless by themselves — they
>    tell you nothing at all about the content of the question.

Above quote from [The Death of Meta Tags](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/) on the [StackOverflow Blog](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/).

Comment: Yeah - I think I agree with that. It also concurs with this answer: http://meta.engineering.stackexchange.com/a/128/95 which I have just found (should do more research before asking questions).

Comment: It rarely hurts to have a specific question for a specific tag, even if the verdict is the same as for some other tag.

Comment: Likewise, per site tagging encourages localization.  Questions that are highly localized tend to have lower lasting value for the over SE system.